# Xamarin Forms - Grouped CollectionView space between headers

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, collectionview

I have a page which displays a grouped collectionview. Some groups have items and some don't. The problem is as follows:

[image]

Why can't I get space between those headers? But it works with the header with no child elements, how come?? How can I fix this, have been searching for ages!

All those headers are datatemplates. Each one of them has a grid. Also, each item is a datatemplate, it also contains a grid.

Xaml Code:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <!--Regular Activity Header-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RegularActivityDataTemplateHeader">
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"  RowSpacing="0">
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Standby Activity Header-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StandbyShiftDataTemplateHeader">
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0"  RowSpacing="0">
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Toweing header-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TowingDataTemplateHeader">
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Footer">
        <BoxView IsVisible="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ActivityToBoolValueConverter}}" Color="AliceBlue" HeightRequest="15"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Regular Activity Cell-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RegularActivityDataTemplateCellA">
    </DataTemplate>

    <!--Data Templace Header Selector-->
    <views:ActivityDataTemplateSelectorHeader x:Key="ActivityTemplateSelectorHeader"
                                         TowingDataTemplateHeader="{StaticResource TowingDataTemplateHeader}"
                                         RegularActivityDateTemplateHeader="{StaticResource RegularActivityDataTemplateHeader}"
                                         StandbyShiftDataTemplateHeader="{StaticResource StandbyShiftDataTemplateHeader}" />

    <!--Data Templace Cell Selector-->
    <views:ActivityTemplateSelectorCell x:Key="ActivityTemplateSelectorCell"
                                         GroepElementA="{StaticResource RegularActivityDataTemplateCellA}"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>
        <RefreshView Margin="10" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <CollectionView x:Name="_collectionView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding PlanningListItems}" 
                        IsGrouped="true"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ActivityTemplateSelectorHeader}"
                        GroupFooterTemplate="{StaticResource Footer}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ActivityTemplateSelectorCell}"
                        SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OpenChosenActivity}">
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Hi , could you share some code of Xaml ? I will have a check with that .

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your reply. How do you want me to share the code? Because it is a lot code that I have at this moment, I don't think I can paste it.

Comment: I discovered that margin top doesn't work. I only can push (with margin) what is beneath the header,  I can't push a header on it self to the bottom. Is this a normal behaviour in xamarin forms?

Comment: How about group footer , does it works for you ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping#customize-the-group-footer

Comment: In addition , there is Item Spacing you can set , have a look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#item-spacing

Comment: I make use of a footer at this moment. In the footer I have placed a boxview, but this seems like a very strange solution, because I now also have to create a ValueConverter to decide when to place that boxview, because there is a special header which doesn't have children that shouldn't have a margin beneath it..

Comment: How about using Item Spacing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#item-spacing

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Item spacing is about the elements under a header. I don't need spacing between them. I need spacing between headers.

Comment: Okey , I think you can share the sample xaml code without data . Then I will know the struct of layout .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I edited the post, I placed the xaml code in it. In the codebehind I also make use of two template selector classes, one for the cells and one for the headers. The model classes are like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping but a little bit different, (using abstract class for the cells, they inherit from it)

Comment: Thanks for updating question . I have runned the sample project from official doc , there is no problem to show space between item .  However , the space background is the same with Item , you can set background color for footer or header to show the space .

Comment: Here is the sample effect : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sBmY.png

Comment: I just don't understand why I need a footer for spacing, why can't I just have a margin at the GRID level that sits in the DateTemplateHeader? (thanks for your reply btw)

Comment: Yes , you can modify that to fit your wants , not necessary use a footer .

Comment: Oke.. weird, I will have a look at the sample later on, thanks!

Comment: Okey , have you solved this now ?